# PHP- Do action if curl takes more than 15 seconds

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending a test curl request to API to test receiving data and cancelling request if the process lasts more than 15 seconds. The problem is the data returns after 30 seconds and I have to check if it takes more than 15 seconds while waiting for it. Here's what I did:

```
for($x=0; $x<$quantity; $x++){
$xmlRequest = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<REQUEST TYPE='PINPRINTING' MODE='DIRECT'>
<AMOUNT>" . $amount . "</AMOUNT>
<PRODUCTID>" . $comp_id . "</PRODUCTID>
<USERNAME>Username</USERNAME>
<PASSWORD>Password</PASSWORD>
</REQUEST>";

 $url = "URL-HERE";
 $headers = array(
     "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
     "Accept: text/xml",
     "Cache-Control: no-cache",
     "Pragma: no-cache",
     "SOAPAction: \"run\""
 );

 try {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);

      $now = time();
      $later =  time();
      for($i=1; $i<16; $i++){

          if(!is_array($data)){
             sleep(1);
             $later += $i;
             if( ($later - $now) >= 15 ){
                echo $now.'<br>'.$later.'<br>';
                echo '<p>It passed 15 seconds</p>';
                $xmlRequest1 = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                <REQUEST TYPE='CANCEL'>
                <AMOUNT>" . $amount . "</AMOUNT>
                <PRODUCTID>" . $comp_id . "</PRODUCTID>
                <USERNAME>Username</USERNAME>
                <PASSWORD>Password</PASSWORD>
                </REQUEST>";

                $headers = array(
                            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                            "Accept: text/xml",
                            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                            "Pragma: no-cache",
                            "SOAPAction: \"run\""
                        );

                try {
                     $ch1 = curl_init();
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest1);
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
                     curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                     $data = curl_exec($ch1);
                     print_r($data);
                     curl_close($ch1);
                    }
                    catch (Exception  $e) {
                          echo 'error occurred<br>';
                         echo 'Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
                       }
                        die('Error');
                    }
                }

                else{
                    if ($data === false) {
                        $error = curl_error($ch);
                        echo $error;
                        die('error occurred');
                    }

                    else {
                        $data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

                        if($data['RESULTTEXT'] == 'transaction successful'){
                            print_r($data);
                        }

                        else{
                            echo "Error: ".$data['RESULTTEXT']."<p>";
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            curl_close($ch);

        }

        catch (Exception  $e) {
            echo '<p>Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
            die("Error");
        }
}
```

I created an internal loop that checks every second if $data is not an array to send the cancellation request but the problem is it keeps waiting 30 seconds (the whole time process to get data even it's invalid) and not 15 seconds.

What I want to do is to check every 15 seconds is data is received or not. If not received it should send the cancellation request without having to wait the whole 30 seconds and not to keep sending the request 15 times if it's valid so if there's data it should be executed just once and exit the internal loop to continue the outer loop ( for(x=0) ...)

Comment: Have you tried `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` ?

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, you're obviously going about this all wrong. you try to send the start of the page - the starting curl before the page is loaded, and send different content on the page depending on wether curl used +15 seconds or not - you'll run in to all sorts of browser-specific (and webserver-specific configuration specific) cache issues with that approach. a much better approach would be with a page with some javascript to start/stop button controlling an Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) starting/stopping the curl requests.

here's an example, 
a.html - containing the GUI control and javascript that counts how many seconds have passed, and lets you abort when you think it has gone too long (for example, abort after 15 seconds)

```
<input id="startRequest" type="button" value="start request" /><br/>
<input id="abortRequest" type="button" value="abort request" /><br/>
seconds running: <span id="runtimeCounter">not started yet</span><br/>
<span id="response">the xhr response will be added here by javascript</span>
<script>
window.xhr;
function count(){
    var xhr=window.xhr;
    var ele=document.querySelector("#runtimeCounter");
    if(!xhr.aborted && xhr.readyState<4){
        ele.textContent=Number(ele.textContent)+1;
    }else{
        ele.textContent+=" completed!";
        clearTimeout(window.count.clearid);
    }
}
document.querySelector("#startRequest").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.querySelector("#runtimeCounter").textContent=0;
    var xhr=window.xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","xhr.php");
    xhr.addEventListener("progress",function(ev){
        var xhr=ev.target;
        document.querySelector("#response").textContent=xhr.responseText;
    });
    xhr.send();
    window.count.clearid=setTimeout(count,1000);
});
document.querySelector("#abortRequest").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var xhr=window.xhr;
    xhr.abort();
    xhr.aborted=true;
    document.querySelector("#runtimeCounter").textContent+=" - aborted";
});

</script>
```

and xhr.php , which actually does the curl stuff:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $quantity; ++$x) {
    $xmlRequest = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<REQUEST TYPE='PINPRINTING' MODE='DIRECT'>
<AMOUNT>" . $amount . "</AMOUNT>
<PRODUCTID>" . $comp_id . "</PRODUCTID>
<USERNAME>Username</USERNAME>
<PASSWORD>Password</PASSWORD>
</REQUEST>";

    $url = "URL-HERE";
    $headers = array (
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "SOAPAction: \"run\"" 
    );

    try {
        $ch = curl_init ();
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
        curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        $data = curl_exec ( $ch );
        curl_close ( $ch );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo '<p>Message: ' . $e->getMessage ();
        die ( "Error" );
    }
}
```

notice here how i set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 0, as this allows the javascript to monitor the download as it progresses - instead of sending everything at the end, like RETURNTRANSFER have to do (it also saves server ram btw, as downloaded content is just stored until its sent to the client, in batches, and discarded, as opposed to storing everything in ram until its 100% downloaded)

- note that this approach is (ab?)using the ignore_user_abort behaviour of PHP, and the abort button won't work if you do `ignore_user_abort(true);` in xhr.php